# Magento Expand or Collapse long text in product descriptions

Tags: magento

I want have JS button like "Expand"/"Collapse" for long texts in my product description. I try to use Readmore.js (https://github.com/jedfoster/Readmore.js):

On the header of my page:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/skin/frontend/default/galarainbow/js/readmore.js"></script>
```

On the footer:

```
<script>
$('#productInfoContainer').readmore();
```

I have "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'readmore' of null" error at Chrome or "TypeError: $(...) is null" at Firefox.

What I am doing wrong? For example, URL is https://goo.gl/dGTayh

Comment: call your script like this `jQuery('#productInfoContainer').readmore();` and if you didnt add jquery library you need to add jquery before readmore.js

Comment: Thank you, Milan, that works! Somehow, a block of text remains with the same height, not expanding down. What could be the problem? https://goo.gl/ybkQPv

Comment: its height problem. make the height auto of `ui-slider-tabs-content-container` div

Comment: Work nice, thank you!